# Can't import PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets

Tags: python, linux, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make an vocabtrainer for myself to get better in english, cause I suck. To achieve this, I'm trying to make a GUI with PyQt5 to expand my programming experience too :). But somehow I can't import the `QtWebEngineWidget`...
This is my code:

```py
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as pyqtW
import PyQt5.QtGui as pyqtG
import PyQt5.QtCore as pyqtC
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

import sys


class VocabTrainer:

    def __init__(self):
        self.main = pyqtW.QApplication([])
        self.window = pyqtW.QWidget()

        self.prepareWindow()

        sys.exit(self.main.exec_())

    def prepareWindow(self):
        """
        Set's the attributes of the window.
        """

        # window settings
        self.window.resize(250, 100)
        self.window.show()

    def openPons(self):
        """
        Opens the website of pons to be able to translate words.
        """
        pass

test = VocabTrainer()
```

My IDE (PyCharm) warns me that it can't find the reference of `PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets` and if I run this code, I'll get this error message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/A/little/path/VocabTrainer.py", line 12, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
ImportError: libQt5Quick.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've installed the modules with the following commands:

```py
pip install pyqt5
pip install pyqtwebengine
```

I've also tried to reinstall the modules but without success.

Python-Version: 3.8.1 
OS: Arch Linux

Comment: execute the following :  `sudo pacman -S mlocate && sudo updatedb && locate libQt5Quick.so.5`

Comment: pycharm is using the system python or is using a virtualenv? If you are using the system python then install the packages from the repositories: `sudo pacman -S python-pyqt5 python-pyqtwebengine`

Comment: @eyllanesc I can't install the `locate` package.

Comment: Ooops se the update comment

Comment: ok I executed `sudo pacman -S mlocate && sudo updatedb && locate libQt5Quick.so.5` but I haven't got any outputs

Comment: execute: `sudo pacman -S python-pyqt5 python-pyqtwebengine`

Comment: didn't change anything... :(

Comment: How have you installed pyqt5? What python are you using: the system or a virtualenv? execute: `sudo pacman -S qt5`

Comment: Well I have a `venv` folder in Pycharm, so I'm guessing that I'm using a virtualenv, btw. Stackoverflow says, that I should avoid extendet discussions in comments and that I should use a chat instead. Should we? Should I install everything of `pacman -S qt5`?

Comment: Yes, install everything. On the other hand, if it still fails, change the interpreter of your project to use the system python.

Comment: Yes! Changing the interpreter to the system python helped! Thank you!!! Do you want to write this as your answer so I can tick it or should I write an answer with a refference to your comment? But I'm still wondering why I can't use the virtualenvironment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of ArchLinux, having the most up-to-date packages, I generally recommend using the repository packages (IMHO Arch Linux is a good laboratory to test the new functionalities :-)). Considering the above, I recommend installing pyq5 and pyqtwebengine by running the following:

```
sudo pacman -S python-pyqt5 python-pyqtwebengine
```

You must also change the python that pycharm uses to the system.

Comment: Thank you again ^^